# Can memcached keys contain spaces?

Tags: php, memcached

I seem to have problems with memcached keys that have spaces, though I can't pinpoint exactly what.

Comment: @Ethan, the results there are talking about a specific Python library that communicates with memcached, not about memcached itself.

Comment: @Ethan I definitely did that search. Basically there was one blog post about it without much detail, and most of the time memcache keys with spaces worked for me. Was hoping to get more info from the helpful SO community.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No.  Memcached keys cannot contain spaces.

Comment: some citation, proof, or reasoning would be nice

Comment: I worked on that part of the core server and I've written many clients and other servers.  The original protocol.txt laid out the key format quite clearly.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what does happen when you have spaces in a key. Does it simply dispose of any get/set operations?

Answer (score 48):

A more explicit answer (referred to by Dustin, but not referenced):

> ### Keys
>
> Data stored by memcached is identified with the help of a key. A key
>   is a text string which should uniquely identify the data for clients
>   that are interested in storing and retrieving it.  Currently the
>   length limit of a key is set at 250 characters (of course, normally
>   clients wouldn't need to use such long keys); the key must not include
>   control characters or whitespace.

Source: [protocol.txt](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) ([Specific Version](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/ab0c0537eb1b225263f4ec45ce3133c5de9a94dc/doc/protocol.txt))

Comment: what are "control characters" ?

Comment: Control characters are \n or \t etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Answer (score 2):

Memcached clients seem not to validate keys in favor of performance.

What I usually do is create a method named `createWellFormedKey($key)` and pass the returned result to the `set()` and `get()` methods of the memcached client.

I do not use md5 and sha1 hashing unless the base64 version exceeds 250 characters. This is because md5 and sha1 are more expensive operations performance wise.

A sample PHP code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Generates a well formed key using the following algorithm:
 * 1. base64_encode the key first to make sure all characters are valid
 * 2. Check length of result, less than 250 then return it
 * 3. Length of result more than 250 then create a key that is md5($validKey).sha1($validKey).strlen($validKey)
 */
private function createWellFormedKey($key) {
    // Get rid of all spaces, control characters, etc using base64
    $validKey = base64_encode($key);

    $validKeyLength = strlen($validKey);
    // 250 is the maximum memcached can handle
    if (strlen($validKey) < 250) {
        return $validKey;
    }

    $validKey = md5($validKey).sha1($validKey).$validKeyLength;
    return $validKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I'm playing around with memcached with PHP and the Problem described IMHO can be easily solved by using hash algorithms like md5 and sha1 (or any other).

I'm using a combination of a md5-hash, sha1-hash and sha256 + the length of the key given.
Obviously this method can be reduced to two hash-methods + length of the key, so you can easily avoid using space or other characters that should not be in the key.

In my opinion the hash-collions are avoided because the chance that both hash algorithms have a collision is nearly 0. By additionally using the key length in the key the problem of a collision is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Applications using the memcached *binary* protocol can use whitespace-containing keys, though there is still a 250-byte length limit.